# Unable to serialize [ 0 1 2 ... 63] to JSON in Keras for DL issues

Tags: python, json, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to create my Neural Network, using Keras, but there are problems once i try to save the model as a ".h5" file. I am using keras

The problem is the following:

> TypeError: Unable to serialize [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
> 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23  24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35
> 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47  48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58
> 59 60 61 62 63] to JSON. Unrecognized type <class
> 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>.

The class related to the problem is:
[PatchEncoder_Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5bvc.png)

Comment: Please never post code as an image!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is coming from `tf.range`, which is an `EagerTensor`. You should use `self.positions.numpy()`. Here is an example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class SomeLayer(tf.keras.layers.Dense):
    def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(units=units, **kwargs)
        self.positions = tf.range(5)

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        config.update({"positions": self.positions.numpy()})
        return config

sl = SomeLayer(5)
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((1,))
outputs = sl(inputs)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.save('model.h5')
```

Comment: seems working using self.positions.numpy() but now i have another problem:

RuntimeError: Unable to create link (name already exists)